# Python nested functions for same parameters

Tags: python, function, nested-function

i have 2 python list and i want to calculate 4 different values using different functions(TP, TN, FP, FN). its better if i can define parameters in outer nested function without defining parameters for each and every functions as parameters are same for all 4 functions.
i have implemented a function, but it gives only the TP function output. could you please someone help me to find the issue here

```
def evaluation(list1,list2):


    def TP():

        count1 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):

            if Jac_test_list[i].strip()==Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='True':
                count1+=1
    #return count

        print ('TP count :' + str( count1))

    return TP

    def TN():
        count2 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):

            if Jac_test_list[i].strip()==Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='False':
                count2+=1
    #return count

        print ('TN count :' + str( count2))
    return TN

    def FP():
        count3 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):

            if (Jac_test_list[i].strip()=='True') & (Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='False'):
                count3+=1
    #return count

        print ('FP count :' + str( count3))
    return FP

    def FN():
        count4 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):

            if (Jac_test_list[i].strip()=='False') & (Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='True'):
                count4+=1
    #return count

        print ('FN count :' + str( count4))
    return FN
```

Comment: Hint: `return` ends the function.  Nothing after your first `return TP` will be executed.

Comment: What do you expect to see when you call evaluation(list1,list2)? Can you give an example?

Comment: Why are you using nested functions here at all? Is this suppose to be a function factory? But then, you are creating closures over `Jac_test_list` and `Simmilar_list`, which are non-local as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Allen below are the expected output                                                                   TP count :12, TN count :16, FP count :1, FN count :6 ,  in other words i want to print all which are in Print() . i have to run this few times. so i like to define parameter in only only place rather than defining them in all 4 functions

Comment: What's your input lists list1 and list2? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say this is not the best way to share parameters among functions but just for the sake of fixing your code, below might be what you are after.

```
def evaluation(Jac_test_list,Simmilar_list):

    def TP():
        count1 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):
            if Jac_test_list[i].strip()==Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='True':
                count1+=1
    #return count
        print ('TP count :' + str( count1))


    def TN():
        count2 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):
            if Jac_test_list[i].strip()==Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='False':
                count2+=1
    #return count
        print ('TN count :' + str( count2))


    def FP():
        count3 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):

            if (Jac_test_list[i].strip()=='True') & (Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='False'):
                count3+=1
    #return count
        print ('FP count :' + str( count3))


    def FN():
        count4 = 0
        for i in range(0,35):
            if (Jac_test_list[i].strip()=='False') & (Simmilar_list[i].strip()=='True'):
                count4+=1
    #return count
        print ('FN count :' + str( count4))

    TP()
    TN()
    FP()
    FN()
```

Comment: thanks very much, this works. if you don't mind can you tell me the best way to share parameters for incidents like this